# Installing Windows 7 destroyed my dual boot setup

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

I have a laptop on which I have two drives with separate Windows XP installs, one barebones for music production, the other "normal" Windows XP with Office etc. (unfortunately the bios won't give a boot disk choice).

Normally I would be presented with two Windows XPs on booting. Selecting the second one would get me into the "normal" installation on disk 1 (C:). Selecting the first in boot order would give me D:\ (disk 2) with the barebones XP.

However, I installed Windows 7 Home onto disk 1 (C:), but there were no dual boot options anymore, even though I installed DualBoot Pro and added Windows XP disk D:.

The options now show up, but selecting Windows XP just turns into a reboot back to where I started.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [EasyBCD 2.0](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1).

Just go to Add/Remove Entries and add a new Windows XP entry. When it asks you to auto-configure, press 'OK' and you'll be set.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the Windows 7 install CD/DVD. Run the installation process, but choose recovery option. There you can open command line and execute "bootrec.exe" tool. It has many options, like /fixboot, /fixmbr. One of options (/scan or it has another name, sounds like this) scans your partitions for existing (lost) operating systems and fix boot errors.